# How to fill linear layout in android?

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

In my android app, I want to create a linear layout horizontally and add a textview on the left side and a progress bar on right right side, I want the textview to wrap content for width. And the progress bar should (for width) take up the remaining space horizontally on the screen.

This is my code:

```
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams percentWidth = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        LinearLayout percentLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        percentLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        percentLayout.setLayoutParams(percentWidth);

        textview = new TextView(this);
        textview.setText(String.format("Tasks Completed: %d%%", personobj.percentage));
        percentLayout.addView(textview);

        ProgressBar checklistprogress = new ProgressBar(this, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);
        checklistprogress.setProgress(personobj.percentage);
        percentLayout.addView(checklistprogress);

        LocationLayout.addView(percentLayout);
```

However this is not working, the progress bar width is not expanding fully. It's only about a centimeter width.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: post your xml code part

Comment: Im not using xml, I am trying to do this all with java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use it

```
 checklistprogress.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a RelativeLayout for this sort of thing. But if you want to use a linear layout, you need to use the `layout_weight` attribute. With layout_weight you can specify a size ratio between multiple views. In the code below the last parameter is the layout weight:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                             LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                             LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f);
```

Have a look at this article for a better understanding of layout_weight
http://www.chess-ix.com/blog/the-use-of-layout_weight-with-android-layouts/

Answer (score 0):

@omega: You can try this code. It is used for changing the style of the progress bar to large.

```
ProgressBar checklistprogress = new ProgressBar(this, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleLarge);
```